# Как работать с API key

Tags: php, api, rest, php7

Есть задача: зарегистрированный пользователь получает доступ к данным уже зарегистрированных пользователей через API, для доступа должен использоваться сгенерированный ключ.

Примитивное API написал, но теперь встал вопрос, как мне сгенерировать этот API ключ?

Вот что я думаю:

```
1. На форме создать скрытое поле token
2. Через $_POST['token'] присвоить что-то вроде hash('md5',$usename)
3. Затем отправить данные в БД (есть специальное поле key)
```

Дальше не особо знаю что да как делать, чтобы в url-строку можно было вставлять этот ключ и только тогда получать ответ от моего API.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой алгоритм действий я должен предпринять для решения этой задачи.

Comment: Нельзя генерировать токен на основании статичных данных пользователя. В приведенном тобой примере с hash('md5',$username) можно сгенерировать токены для любого пользователя зная только всего лишь его логин (можно банально подобрать).

Comment: Правильно было бы генерировать токен после того как пользователь прислал свой логин пароль, на основании их и случайного числа (или текущей даты) генерировать токен и сохранять его в базу данных. Каждый раз когда пользователь присылает тебе логин и пароль, ты сообщаешь ему этот токен и далее он уже вместо логина/пароля прикрепляет к своим запросам этот токен.